# Windows C drive got mismatched

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, ubuntu-18.04, partition-recovery, diskpart

I just messed up things while installing Ubuntu Windows C drive (where all the Windows files are installed) has been mismatched. Actually, in the partition list (according to the image posted) partition 3 corresponds to Windows files and its type is shown as "System" instead of primary.

And in list volume section Volume 3 (Windows-ssd) is the one where Windows files are present its letter isn't showing and even the Info column it shows "hidden".

[image]

Comment: Just click on text you'll find the image

Comment: Now I can't turn on windows. It freezes after a greyish screen appears.

Comment: Try [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Not working I just see the last image (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: You mean "Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC"? Did the repair at least see your Windows installation on the disk?

Comment: You likely have significant disk issues and/or hardware issues. You should probably take your computer to a competent local hardware technician.